# Как сделать рамку?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать рамку, как это показано на скрин шоте (выделение синим цветом).

[image: Синяя рамка вокруг блока]

при том у меня вот такой скрипт

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<table align='center' width='26%'>
<tr>
<td colspan='0'><img src="/images/В online.png" alt='' /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='25'>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
             Логин: 
    <br />
    <input name="login" id="login" type="text" />
    <br />
    Пароль:
    <br />
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: #6286ab;" value="Войти" />
        </form>
     </td><td>

<span style='position: relative;bottom: 42px;margin-left:-4px'><img src="/images/welcome.gif"></span>
</td> 
</tr><table>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<table align='center' width='26%'>
<tr>
<td colspan='0'><img src="/images/В online.png" alt='' /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='25'>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
             Логин: 
    <br />
    <input name="login" id="login" type="text" />
    <br />
    Пароль:
    <br />
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: #6286ab;" value="Войти" />
        </form>
   </td><td style="border: 3px solid blue;">

<span style='position: relative;bottom: 42px;margin-left:-4px'><img src="/images/welcome.gif"></span>
</td> 
</tr><table>
```

Comment: а как мне заменить на другой цвет?
например бледно голубой?

Comment: [Яндекс, со своими фичами в помощь](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9&lr=193)

border: 3px solid #42aaff;

и всё таки http://htmlbook.ru/faq  (:

Comment: или плагин для FireFox ColorZilla. Сам юрзаю

Answer (score 3):

Установи `Firebug` и посмотри сам, как же сделано.

А так по виду типичный `border`:

```
border: 6px solid blue;
```

Comment: не получается(

Comment: Что тут может не получится?
<style>
.block{
 border: 6px solid blue;

 width: 700px;
 min-height: 500px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
<div class="block"></div>

и, да, всё таки ознакомитесь с http://htmlbook.ru/faq